# setting default parameters to sessions in Informatica Workflow Manager

Tags: informatica-powercenter

In Informatica Workflow Manager 9.5.1, I want my sessions to have some specific default parameters, e.g. I want the "Target Load Type" to be normal by default.

How can I define default parameters for new sessions?

The parameters I want to change are:

- (The most important) When Informatica encounters a number without a specified precision, it automatically asssumes it is a double, and hence gives it a precision of 15. I want the default to be bigint, for avoiding roundings.
- Target Load Type" (normal)
- "Fail parent if task failed" (marked)
- Mapping->Connections->*$Target Connection value* should have some specific default value (I can't provide a screenshot)
- Mapping -> Targets->Properties-> delete (unmarked)

There seems to be no one place in the menus where all default values can be tuned, and no one in my team knows.

Comment: Hello there, could you please post some examples of what you have tried so far, or a problem that you have encountered?

Comment: Tried searching in the menus, problem is parameters have to be changed in every single session to the same things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify which parameters you want changed. 
The "Target Type Load" default is set in the Workflow Manager application, in the menu Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous. In the "Target Load Type" section there are radio buttons for Normal and Bulk.

Comment: Great. I added the other params in the post.